# Does SubmitField need a validator?

Tags: python, wtforms

I am new to WTForms. I've got a user registration form with a submit button:

```
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

I want to ensure the form is submitted via pressing the submit button and not some other way. In the [docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html) it states that

```
class wtforms.fields.SubmitField(default field arguments)
Represents an <input type="submit">. This allows checking if a given submit button has been pressed.
```

Which raises a question: For my case, do I need to add a "Required" validator?

e.g., does it need to be:

```
submit = SubmitField('Submit', [validators.Required()])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you do. Looking at the source code there is nothing that would make a `SubmitField` required.

The `SubmitField` is really just a `BooleanField`:

```
class SubmitField(BooleanField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="submit">``.  This allows checking if a given
    submit button has been pressed.
    """
    widget = widgets.SubmitInput()
```

The associated widget is just an Input widget that has type="submit". It also seems to use the label of the SubmitField as the text in in the HTML.

```
class SubmitInput(Input):
    """
    Renders a submit button.

    The field's label is used as the text of the submit button instead of the
    data on the field.
    """
    input_type = 'submit'

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs): 
        kwargs.setdefault('value', field.label.text)
        return super(SubmitInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

It doesn't seem to do much more than this.